# Email notification when a certain date is reached - Microsoft Azure

Tags: azure

is there a way to receive an e-mail notification when a certain date is reached?

Because in my infrastructure I'm using an oAuth 2.0 API logic and I want to be notified when the client secret for the token generation is going to expire.

I have seen that in Azure Monitor Alert Rule, it is necessary to select a target resource and a scope, but the notification that I want to create is only based on the selected date.

Comment: You could try a [Logic App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-overview) or a [Function App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-overview) with a daily trigger, which then checks the date and sends an e-mail as soon as the date matches the date you want to send the e-mail.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, since I'm not a developer, is there a simpler way to do this? If not could you provide me with more details, like the code that i have to put in the function app?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a one-stop-code-shop, so providing code is not what this site is intended for. Logic Apps are a no-code solution, enabling non-developers to create logic visually. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a way to create **email** notification when a certain date is reached.

Thanks to **rickvdbosch** for suggesting **Logic Apps** feature.

You can use Logic apps to trigger the email notification.

1. Create an app registration and create one secret.

**Azure Portal >Azure Active Directory > App registrations > New Registration**

[image]

2. Assign permission in app and grant the permission.

[image]

3. To secure HTTP action you can use Azure Key vault to store the secrets.
4. Create azure Key vault

**Azure Portal > Key vault > Create**

[image]

5. Create Secrets in **Azure Key Vault.**

[image]

7. Create a Logic App.

**Azure Portal > Logic Apps > Create.**

[image]

Follow the [document](https://www.inthecloud247.com/get-notified-on-expiring-azure-app-registration-client-secrets/) created by **Peter** to follow the Logic Apps flow to trigger the email when a certain date is reached.